# How should I interpret these ACF / PACF plots for a time series?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation

I am trying to determine the most appropriate degree of difference to start building an arima model for this dataset. I already know that I need a first difference, but there is a seasonal component and I am not exactly sure where to go from here. I've tried several potential options but I am just not very confident when interpreting these plots. I will include the raw time series plot / acf / pacf plots as well as the first differenced time series / acf / pacf plots. Any help would be fantastic!!

Original:
[Time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA9lx.png)

[acf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Eqa.png)

[pacf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3VJI.png)

First Difference:

[first diff time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zxqF.png)

[first diff acf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0mVt.png)

[first diff pacf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlEcB.png)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting the results of statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. These aren't programming questions, these are statistical questions.

Comment: Thank you, I will post the question there!

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions. If you wish to have a question moved, flag it for migration.